# JavaFx application in web browser : Jar working but JNLP / HTML doesn't

Tags: java, deployment, applet, javafx-2, jnlp

I have a javafx application, i am using netbeans as IDE. If i use the configuration stand alone the program is working without any trouble. But if  i choose Run in browser i have a Runtime Error and the strack trace is pretty much empty :

```
Plug-in Java 10.21.2.11
Utilisation de la version JRE 1.7.0_21-b11 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
Répertoire d'origine de l'utilisateur = C:\Users\Julien
----------------------------------------------------
...
----------------------------------------------------
CacheEntry[file:/C:/Users/Julien/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FittsLaw/dist/lib/eclipselink-2.3.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Wed May 15 11:26:16 CEST 2013,length=6770392
CacheEntry[file:/C:/Users/Julien/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FittsLaw/dist/lib/javax.persistence-2.0.3.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Wed May 15 11:26:19 CEST 2013,length=143654
CacheEntry[file:/C:/Users/Julien/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FittsLaw/dist/FittsLaw.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Wed May 15 11:26:08 CEST 2013,length=166805
CacheEntry[file:/C:/Users/Julien/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FittsLaw/dist/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Wed May 15 11:26:22 CEST 2013,length=805863
```

If i try to deploy it, the JAR is working, but JNLP/HTML are leading to the same Runtime error.

I don't know where i must search because this runtime error doesn't give me a lot of information. 
I have tried :

- different browsers
- Update/reinstall plugin/jre/jdk

I have found lot of topic about it, but most of them got Classnotfound exception where it seems my problem isn't the same because i never got it in the stacktrace.

Comment: Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to open for applets and has the info. level turned up to 5.

Comment: Doesn't JNLP/HTML required the jars to be signed?

Comment: Not always Perneel, but signing is required in Julien's case as he connects to a database and that requires [enhanced permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABJGFBH).

Comment: You can get more debug info by following the [Oracle Troubleshooting guide for Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html).

Comment: Post your JNLP script here.

Comment: I'm sorry, i figured out what was wrong. I got some JPA code related which was not disable, and i wanted to disable all JPA because i was trying a test deploy without DB cover.

Comment: Btw i still don't know why the stacktrace was empty, any clues ? It should said me that BD connection failed isn't it ?